# Google maps JS API shows blue focus border

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps JS API began displaying blue focus border around the map after switching to another browser tab and then go back. Once the map is clicked the border vanishes. 
The element with the border is generated by Gmaps and within their DOM. Border seems to show only in full-page map display.
[image]

Tracing Gmap DOM show a border at child of gm-style: (div.gm-style > div)

```
<div style="pointer-events: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;
           box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; z-index: 1000002;
           opacity: 0; border: 2px solid rgb(26, 115, 232);"></div>
```

The opacity: 0 is dynamic and change to opacity: 1 after click to another browser tab.
Why Gmaps JS API like this works? Any idea how to clearly remove this square from viewpoint?

Edit:

- blue square shows in Chrome 89 && Mozilla 86
- Steps: open js fiddle link -> focus the map (easy roll map from side to side) -> change browser tab -> go back to tab with jsfiddle example -> blue square
  [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gjL1wrxd/)

Opened issue as bug:
[Google Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182937497)

Comment: Seems to show this square from Maps JavaScript API version 3.43

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. What browser are you using? If I look at the [simple map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) in Chrome, this does not happen.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gjL1wrxd/

Comment: You should open a new bug in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853). This seems to only happen with `v=3.44` and `v=3.43`. Version `3.42` does not behave this way. Please cross-link your question in your bug report and the bug report in your question once open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue closed as a google maps bug. Bug will be fixed in next GMApi release.
[Issuetracker Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182937497?pli=1)

Comment: Issue seems to not be fixed. Had to use the solution of @SeaTheme

Comment: just happened to me too and thankfully I didnt waste time trying to debug it

Comment: Issue was not fixed.

Comment: Issue not fixed as of Feb 2024. To fix it, add the following to your css

 .gm-style iframe + div { border:none!important; }

Comment: 2024 - The issue is still not fixed.

Comment: Still not fixed Mar 2024, also I'd argue this isn't a bug but rather just UX design (not adding an easy way to customize/disable the border).

Answer (score 36):

I met the same issue,  the CSS works:

`.gm-style iframe + div { border:none!important; }`

Comment: Legit lifesaver tysm

Comment: Removing focus indicators is bad practice in general. It's recommended to instead target this selector and customize the indicator to match the style of the page the map is embedded into. The Google Maps code will adjust the `opacity` from `0` to `1` when the Map is focused, so any customisation regarding the focus indicator will work (except for `opacity`).
Upvoted nevertheless, because finding this selector is painful anyway, so great help. Thanks!